# Capturing a reference to object causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++14

When capturing a reference by reference or by copy the call to `name()` causes segmentation fault.
With `std::bind` there is no problem. Why?

```
struct with_name
{
    template<typename T>
    explicit with_name(T& t)
            : // name([&]{return t.name();})
            name(std::bind(&T::name, &t))
    {}
    std::function<const std::string&()> name;
};

struct Person
{
    const std::string& name() const
    {
        return name_;
    }
    std::string name_ = "Jon";
};

int main()
{
    Person person{};

    with_name withName{person};

    // segmentation fault
    std::cout << withName.name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

From cppreference:

Notes
Care should be taken when a std::function whose result type is a reference is initialized from a lambda expression without a trailing-return-type. Due to the way auto deduction works, such lambda expression will always return a prvalue. Hence, the resulting reference will usually bind to a temporary whose lifetime ends when std::function::operator() returns.

```
std::function<const int&()> F([]{ return 42; });
int x = F(); // Undefined behavior: the result of F() is a dangling reference
```

Also from cppreference:

```
template< class F >
function( F f );
```

5. Initializes the target with std::move(f). If f is a null pointer to function or null pointer to member, *this will be empty after the call. This constructor does not participate in overload resolution unless f is Callable for argument types Args... and return type R.

---

So why does not it work when you pass a callable object outside, but when you create it in the scope of arguments it is UB? Isn't it copyable?

Comment: It works in CLang 11 and GCC 10. What compiler do you use?

Comment: @Rem MinGW64 (GCC 10). Did you uncomment the line when a lambda is used? Because otherwise the code works with `std::bind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not capturing a reference, but the return type of the lambda doesn't match the signature of `std::function`. Given `[&]{return t.name();}`, the return type would be `std::string`, but `name` expects returning `const std::string&`.

Change the lambda to

```
template<typename T>
explicit with_name(T& t)
        :  name([&] () -> decltype(auto) {return t.name();})
        //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //                deduce return type as const string& when `T` is Person
{}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. It is said to be a UB to initialize `std::function` that way... Why?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Because the returned reference of `std::function` is always dangled, trying to use it like `std::cout << withName.name() << std::endl;` leads to UB.